# iOS select onchange not firing

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, onchange

Does anyone know any workarounds for this? I'm trying to use a select element for navigation. It looks something like this;

```
<select onchange="window.location=(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

It works on all desktop browsers and it also works on my WP7 phone. It doesn't work on my iPhone (iOS 5.0).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

iOS tends to not fire `change` events when you change the value of their inputs. I've [documented this in more depth at the Device-Bugs tracker](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/25).

The workaround is to bind to the `blur` event instead. In the above example, use `onblur` and you'll be all set.

```
<select onblur="window.location=(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

Comment: They do fire the event right after the user "clicks" the option thats the thing... So its not the "done" events that will fire the change. So yes the blur is prefered in this case. Its a crap this fragmentation...

Answer (score 7):

If you change `onchange` to `onblur` it works for iOS but not others.  The fix I eventually came to was to use BOTH `onblur` and `onchange`.  Seems redundant but has the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up setting the form action to a php page that redirects the page. You don't even need a submit button (although you may as well add one for graceful degradation then hide it with js), the iOS list picker widget automatically triggers the form action when it's 'Done' button is pressed.

I originally wanted to avoid form actions and submit buttons because I felt the js onChange approach was cleaner, but I'm fine with using php on iOS since it doesn't require the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `input`event ([See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).