# Select navigation compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `select` navigation as follows, which works fine on desktop browsers:

```
<select onchange="window.location=this.value;">
```

But this doesn't work in Mobile Safari, so `onblur` is needed instead.

Is there an `on` event that is cross-compatible?

Comment: It's worth noting that I considered using a drop-down `div` to get around this issue, which would be more natural for the way Mobile Safari handles `select` but I'm still curious for when using `select` in a genuine `form`.

Comment: What specifically "doesn't work"?

Comment: I have not tried it with `window.location`, but with `location.href` it works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't fire `onchange`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/ios-select-onchange-not-firing

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").on('change', function () { $(this).trigger('blur'); })
   .on('blur', function () {
       window.location = $(this).val();
   });
```