# javascript onchange for select not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

Hi i have this little function on my nav for a select that appear when the window is too short to show the hole nav menu, and with a javascript function I manage to redirect the user to the page by giving the location ref as the option value. Until there everything work just fine, but the idea of this is to make it work for cell browser, for what i'm trying it on an iPhone and it just don't do a thing. wonder if somebody could see something to fix or anything??

function in matter:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var nav1 = document.getElementById('nav1');
    nav1.onchange = function(){
        location.href= nav1.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe onclick event will help you?

Comment: also share html code.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/ios-select-onchange-not-firing

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answer in [iOS select onchange not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/ios-select-onchange-not-firing) referenced by itsgoingdown, it seems that what work like god but not so smooth in pc, is to put a "onblur" action directly on the select tag and reference to a change the location to the value of selected item; example with html code below, for if it help anyone on the future. The problem on pc is that somehow you need to make a click out of the select box to trigger the "onblur" action, if i found a way to make it smoother i will let you know, by now if anyone figure it out before be welcome to show me (i love to learn new ways, as all).

A lintel explanation on the onblur itself is that window.location, like the name say it, change the location to what is given as reference. in the second part all the parts that says "this" are referencing the select itself, option to each option and value to the value of the option selected with is referenced by "selectedIndex". So after that you only need to put in the value of each option (in this case each of the categories of a table) the destiny that you want to been taken.

```
<select id="nav1" onblur="window.location=(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option> Seleccionar Destino </option>
    <?php
        foreach(takeallinorder('categories', 'order') as $order => $cat){

echo "<option value='", $cat['destiny'] ,"'>", $name, "</option>";
} ?>
</selected>
```

Comment: I put my answer on the original question stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/… modified and made a snippet. But blur event is doing the thing, cheers  ;-)