# JQuery - On change for select for Safari not reading option values

Tags: jquery, select, safari

JQuery on change for select not reading option values properly in Safari. 
I have tried:
- switching different versions of jquery
- made sure it's loaded before other scripts
- tried with .live instead of .change.
- I've tried .on(change) too but same results on Safari.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ac87eemp/

It works fine in Chrome/Firefox. In Safari, the output defaults to the else condition and outputs this (inside a textbox input value):

> ERROR!!!

HTML:

```
<div class="abc">
<select name="blahblah">
    <option value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.abc select').change(function () {
    var target = $('.abc select option:selected').val();

    if(target === 'option 1'){
        function displayText(){
        var txt = 'hello 1';

            $('.textbox input').val(txt);
            $('.textbox input').attr('value', txt);

        }
    }
    else if(target === 'option 2'){
        function displayText(){
        var txt = 'hello 2';

            $('.textbox input').val(txt);
            $('.textbox input').attr('value', txt);

        }
    }
    else{
        function displayText(){
        var txt = 'ERROR!!!';

            $('.textbox input').val(txt);
            $('.textbox input').attr('value', txt);
        }
    }

    return displayText();
});
```

Comment: Do you have more than one `.abc select`? You set `target` to the value of the first one, not the one that the user is currently changing.

Comment: I just checked and am sure I have only that one select tag

Comment: Can you add the HTML to your question and make it an executable [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)?

Comment: This is the problem with iOS as well, you can try with `blur` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/ios-select-onchange-not-firing

Comment: Are you sure Safari isn't doing anything funny to the spaces in the option values?

Comment: JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ac87eemp/

As you can see, it defaults to else condition in Safari :(. That blur fix didn't work. I even found an equivalent workaround with on change as the select attribute but didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the function inside the conditions.

So I removed displayText() from all code. Safari apparently has a problem with returning functions from conditions.