# Select input onChange event not working in Firefox browser for php responsive website

Tags: php, html, select, onchange

my code are:-

```
  <select name="Priore" id="prioe" onchange="return showcolor()">
        <option> </option>
        <option value = "1">Red</option>
        <option value = "2">Blue</option>
  </select>
```

Show color function:-

```
  function showcolor()

    {

     alert('test');

    }
```

But, onchange event not working, Alert event not fire in Firefox browser.
     In chrome browser working proper.

In Firefox showcolor() function not working for iphone 6/7/8+ display.

How to Solved that issue?

Comment: `In Firefox onchnage() function not working.` In Firefox, it is working correctly. By the way, please post your concrete html code for more detail

Comment: In leptop and other screen function working proper, but in iphone 6/7/8 + not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS select onchange not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/ios-select-onchange-not-firing)

Comment: No onblur event not working. Sorry Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved,

Any Website opened in iPhone Firefox browser any drop-down not open, it's actually not a issue(drop-down in working condition).

Testing drop-down in mobile iPhone then drop-down work properly.