# Dropdown item selection not working on iphones

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using this code to generate a dropdown list, That is working fine on pc and android
but will not work on iphone the iphone display the list but will not respond to the touch of a selected item. 
Any thought on how it could be modified to also work on the iphones

```
 <script type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
    <?
     var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GerAhvhytiKKrOUCTiavVuPRJAT9uYYRje2d85E8C-8").getSheetByName("Name Data");
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
     var myRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastRow); 
     var data    = myRange.getValues();
    ?>

 </script>  

<div class="row"> 
  <div class="input-field">
   <i class="material-icons prefix">person</i>
    <select id="Name" >
    <option value=""  disabled selected>Select your name</option>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
   <option ><?!= data[i] ?></option>
  <? } ?>
 </select>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recall having an issue with iOS not firing the select event and me using the blur event instead:

```
<select onblur="doSomething">
```

Maybe you have the same issue.

Edit: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004227/ios-select-onchange-not-firing) similar question for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response so instead of <select id="Name" > it would be <select onblur id="Name"